# CSS rollover - background image wont center

Tags: css, rollover, background-position

I have a rollover top menu. Im trying to get it so my background image (17px x 13px) appears on hover in the center. I've tried all the background css attributes and nothing seems to work. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Here is my CSS:

```
#navlist a:hover
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b2b85c;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(Images/pointer.jpg);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Here is a link to the page.

http://kerrydean.ca/Grey%20River/greyRiverTemplate2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By navigation I assume you mean the top menu.

Try adding `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to your CSS rule for `#navlist a:hover`

Comment: thx. That helped! now I just need the "pointer" to display in the center. any thoughts on that?

Comment: Hi "background-position: 50% bottom;" may work, I have never used 'center' before myself.

Comment: Actually, "center" may be fine, the issue is the inline styles on your "A" elements overriding the rules in the external style sheets:

<a href="test.html" style="border:none;background-position:0px bottom">HOME</a>

Comment: I ended up overriding the css rules for each link beacuseI couldnt get it to center in the css. looks good in safari but is messed up in firefox...damn